# Как выровнять блоки разной высоты на всех разрешениях?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, изображения

Есть блок `bootostrap` с картинками неизвестного изначально размера (могут быть любыми) 4 штуки, 1 ряд. Как выровнять их в ряду на всех разрешениях? кроссбраузерность `ie9+` [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26945/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="anchor" class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#new-tab">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/67x67">
      <p>подпись</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#calculator">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/47x66">
      <p>подпись</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#application">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/92x67">
      <p>подпись</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#guarantee">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/58x70">
      <p>подпись</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите после второго блока картинки (div-a) такой код для того чтобы исправить проблему сворачивания колонок.

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
```

[Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/550e4aqw/)

Почитать подробнее можно на [официальном сайте bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)